# Calling std::any_of with conditional operator on lambda gives unexpected results

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, conditional-operator, std

Here is some code I recently wrote in VS2012:

```
    ///<summary>Lambda: Returns true if the field is significant within a baseline context</summary>
    const auto IsSignificantBaselineField = [](const field_info & field)->bool
    {
        //Some lines removed here!
        return something;
    };

    ///<summary>Lambda: Returns true if the field is significant within a project context</summary>
    const auto IsSignificantProjectField = [&IsSignificantBaselineField](const field_info & field)->bool
    {
        if (!IsSignificantBaselineField (field))
            return false;

        //Some lines removed here!
        return something_else;
    };

    return std::any_of (modified_fields.begin (), modified_fields.end (), (proj_id == 0) ? IsSignificantProjectField : IsSignificantBaselineField);
```

Oddly, when 'proj_id = 90000', IsSignificantProjectField is being called by std::any_of, whereas my intention is that IsSignificantBaselineField would be called in this case.

Please can anyone explain the fault in my logic?

Comment: This compiles? It should not. There is no common type between the type of both lambdas.

Comment: Yeah, it compiles cleanly in VS2012.  It hadn't occurred to me that there's no common type, but that sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: Someone here in the office has just tried something similar in a basic console application and it doesn't compile.  I guess there's some subtle bug in the compiler that allowed it to compile (but not work) in my case.

Comment: haha! I recommend you experiment a bit further so you can pinpoint the issue better.

Comment: Thanks @R Martinho Fernandes.  You're probably right.  I'm not sure I want to push this too far though.  I've tried reporting bugs with Microsoft before, and I just couldn't get their buglog system to work in my browser.  Hopefully they've improved it since then.

Comment: Well, it's not just about reporting it. As is, no one can help with your problem because we cannot reproduce it (it doesn't compile for us!). Figuring out what makes your code compile would help us explain how to fix your problem, or at least coming up with a workaround.

Comment: I'll have a quick play with changing the lambda contents and capture, just in case that then stops it compiling.  Is there anything else you'd suggest?  Finding any number of workarounds shouldn't be difficult, I was just perplexed as to why it was giving strange results.

Comment: Actually, here you go: if I remove the capture of 'IsSignificantBaselineField' from 'IsSignificantProjectField' then it gives a compile error (C2446): no conversion from...

Comment: Is there anything else you'd like me to try tweaking to see what effect it has?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I tried `auto x = (i < 100) ? a : b;` where `const auto a = []{return false;};` and `const auto b = []{return true;};` in g++ 4.8 it compiles. Is this incorrect by standards? i.e. if the prototypes of the lambda are the same, can this be done? VC++ cried _No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion_.

Comment: @legends2k that one is correct, because the *captureless* lambdas are convertible to function pointers. AFAIK VS doesn't implement that yet.

Comment: Thanks for furthering this discussion, @legends2k.  Very interesting!

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Aah, `captureless lambdas are convertible to function pointers`, good to know, thanks!
@Coder_Dan: Just my two cents :)

Comment: @r.martinhofernandes captureless lambda to function pointer works in vs2012.  It may even be overly aggressive, in that I have seen them convert what I thought was needlessly.

Comment: @Yakk: I tried this with the `cl.exe` that comes with Visual Studio 2012, `17.00.60315.1` to be exact; from what I get, seems like they've'nt implemented it yet.

Comment: If it's relevant, I could also get these lines to compile cleanly:
        `const auto l1 = (proj_id == LOCAL_PROJECT_UNIQUE_ID) ? IsSignificantProjectField  : IsSignificantBaselineField;
        const auto l2 = (proj_id != LOCAL_PROJECT_UNIQUE_ID) ? IsSignificantBaselineField : IsSignificantProjectField;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So here's my guess why the code compiles and shows the behavior you observe.

The lambdas are both converted to structs by the compiler.

One has no captures, and thus no members and a no-arg constructor.

```
struct IsSignificantBaselineField_Lambda {
  bool operator ()(const field_info & field) { ... }
};
```

The other has one capture, translated to one member and a single-arg constructor.

```
struct IsSignificantProjectField_Lambda {
  IsSignificantProjectField_Lambda(IsSignificantBaselineField_Lambda& capture1)
    : m_capture1(capture1) {}
  bool operator ()(const field_info & field) {
    if (!m_capture1(field)) return false;
    ...
  }
private:
  IsSignificantBaselineField_Lambda& m_capture1;
};
```

My bet is that the compiler's transformation doesn't make that constructor `explicit`, thus making it a converting constructor, which means that IsSignificantBaselineField is convertible to IsSignificantProjectField, and thus IsSignificantProjectField is the common type of the two. So the call is equivalent to:

```
return std::any_of (modified_fields.begin (), modified_fields.end (),
    (proj_id == 0) ? IsSignificantProjectField :
                     IsSignificantProjectField_Lambda(IsSignificantBaselineField));
```

The net effect is that both branches do the same thing.

This is of course a compiler bug.

Comment: Brilliant - well deduced!  That may well be the correct explanation.